# Understanding IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

in my page i have several img tags as follow:

```
<img class="img-fluid meeseks" src="img/meeseks_red.jpg" data-color="#ee5b61" />
```

in the js file i've created this:

```
function Store(path,color){
    this.path=path
    this.color=color}
```

and then, starting writing the code, i wrote this:

```
img_path=[]
    for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        img_path.push( new Store(img[i].getAttribute("src"),img[i].getAttribute("data-color")))
    }
```

to obtain an array of object that stores the src and color of every image.

Now, studying the IIFE, i wrote this that also seems works:

```
(function store_inf(){
    img_path=[]
    for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        img_path.push( new Store(img[i].getAttribute("src"),img[i].getAttribute("data-color")))
    }
    return img_path

})()
```

Which way is better in this case? I also noticed that if i omitted return things works normally (i always have an array of object if i log the img_path arrays)

So the IIFE return an array that is permanent, even after IIFE has been invoked, in the global scope?
thanks

Comment: No. if you use a variable without declaring it, it becomes part of the global scope. The iife is useless.

Comment: ok the correct solution is:  var img_path=[]
 for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
  img_path.push( new Store(img[i].getAttribute("src"),img[i].getAttribute("data-color")))
 }?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code works because img_path is actually *global* and your IIFE is useless. You may do:

```
var img_path=(function(){
var img=document.getElementByTagName("img");
var img_path=[];//now local
for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
    img_path.push( new Store(img[i].getAttribute("src"),img[i].getAttribute("data-color")))
}
return img_path
})()
```

Now theres an enclosed img_path and img array and a global img_path.

Note that you could also do:

```
var img_path=document.querySelectorAll("img").values().map(el=>new Store(el.src,el.getAttribute("data-color")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `img_path` is global has nothing to do with IIFE. It is global because you have not declared it with the `var` keyword. Everything that is not declared with `var` (or `const`, or `let`) will be attached to the global scope, in your case it will be attached to the `window` object. Just try `console.log(window.img_path)` after your IIFE (or not IIFE) code version.

I would recommend you start using `use strict` in your js, as it will point out more "unobvious" errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should care a bit more about semicolons, they're not for leisure but because you need them. There are edge cases where ambiguity is introduced without semicolons. That said, you don't need the function namen and you don't need to return anything if you don't use the result by any means (as an argument or an assignment). You also don't need the store function, it really doesn't do much, just use JS object literals as shown below. The function may also be written as:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var i, img_path;

  img_path = [];
  for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++)
  {
    img_path.push({
      "path": img[i]["src"],
      "color": img[i]["data-color"]
    });
  }

  // TODO: use img_path here because outside this function scope it does not exist
}());
// ^ better parens placement
```

For more information on how to write clean code and adhere to open-source JS style look up JSLint and similar tools. You'll see how many style errors such a tool gives you.

Answer (score 1):

The IIFE here is not really the part that's blowing your mind.

In JavaScript, you must declare your variables. If you are using JS in the browser, and you aren't using strict-mode (you should be, once you have a better handle on the language), you'll know why these things are occurring.

```
var x = 1;

function makeGlobalsHappen () {
  y = 2;
  var z = 4;
}

makeGlobalsHappen();
x; // 1
y; // 2
z; // ERROR! z is not defined
```

That had nothing to do with the IIFE (of which, I have none).

Were I in ES5's opt-in strict-mode, or using modern JS modules (which are strict by design):

```
const x = 1;
const makeGlobals = () => {
  y = 2; // ERROR! y is undefined
  const z = 4;
};
makeGlobals(); // *BOOM*
```